# how to put the time of the session variable longer?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

[image]

I'm trying to increase my session variable time but they always end up expiring in the default time.

In the image you can see that `session.gc_maxlifetime` changes in the local value but does not change in master value.

What should I do so that `session.gc_maxlifetime` lasts longer so that session variables are not precosily deleted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Try also changing `session.cookie_lifetime` duration